# How to get values with out sum?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

My input like below.

```
+----+-------+---------+----------+----+----+
| A  | B     |    C    |  D       | E  | F  |
+----+-------+---------+----------+----+----+
| 3  | 32447 |  168531 | 2/2/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 4  | 32447 |  168531 | 2/3/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 14 | 32447 |  168531 | 2/6/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 14 | 32447 |  168531 | 2/6/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 12 | 32447 |  168531 | 2/7/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 12 | 32447 |  168531 | 2/7/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 12 | 32447 |  168531 | 2/7/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 46 | 32447 |  168531 | 2/8/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 46 | 32447 |  168531 | 2/8/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 46 | 32447 |  168531 | 2/8/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 85 | 32447 |  168531 | 2/9/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 85 | 32447 |  168531 | 2/9/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 85 | 32447 |  168531 | 2/9/2017 | 10 | 20 |
+----+-------+---------+----------+----+----+
```

My Expected output  like

```
+----+-------+--------+----------+----+----+
| A  | B     | C      | D        | E  | F  |
+----+-------+--------+----------+----+----+
| 3  | 32447 | 168531 | 2/2/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 4  | 32447 | 168531 | 2/3/2017 | 10 | 20 |
| 14 | 32447 | 168531 | 2/6/2017 | 20 | 40 |
| 12 | 32447 | 168531 | 2/7/2017 | 30 | 60 |
| 46 | 32447 | 168531 | 2/8/2017 | 30 | 60 |
| 85 | 32447 | 168531 | 2/9/2017 | 30 | 60 |
+----+-------+--------+----------+----+----+
```

i am using query like

```
select b,c,d,sum(e),sum(f)
group by b,c,d
```

how to get A column values with out MAX concept? Thanks.

Comment: cant you just include A in the columns you select and also add it on the group by columns.

Comment: @BennjoeMordeno .But A column is number datatype

Comment: Numeric datatype shouldnt cause problems with grouping afaik

Comment: With your sample data, adding `a` to `group by` will do the job. Why isn't this good for you? Please post an example that shows why aggregating by `a` is  not a solution for your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(a),b,c,d,sum(e),sum(f)
group by b,c,d
```

Comment: Ok  but i am trying without MAX concept

Comment: What do you want? for example there are 2 A values 3 and 4 what do you want to choose? 4 without max function?

Comment: A column values is always unique like below                                              12 32447 168531 2/7/2017
12 32447 168531 2/7/2017
12 32447 168531 2/7/2017

Comment: select a,b,c,d,sum(e),sum(f)  from mytable
group by a,b,c,d

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM` function with `GROUP BY` clause.

**Query**

```
select a, b, c, d, sum(e) e, sum(f) f
from your_table_name
group by a, b, c, d;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a,b,c,d,sum(e)e,sum(f)f FROM Table_Name
group by a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.. Hope this will work for you

```
select a,b,c,d,sum(e),sum(f) FROM yourtable out_TB
WHERE A=(SELECT TOP 1 in_TA.A FROM yourtable in_TA WHERE in_TA.A=out_TB.A ORDER BY in_TA.A DESC)
group by a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.* FROM
(
   ...your query here...
 ) r
ORDER BY 1
/
```